# Localizing the default back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I want to localize the default back button which appears when new view controller is pushed. I tried adding a custom back button using `hidesbackbutton = true`.
But, this does not show up my custom button anyhow.

Is there any approach, I can use to localize the default back button?

Comment: In what way do you need to localize the default back button? The default back button simply shows an arrow and the previous view's title. Or it may show "Back" but that will automatically be localized along with the rest of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create custom backButtonItem:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navButton = UIButton()
    let localizedBack = NSLocalizedString("back", comment: "")
    navButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40)
    navButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
    navButton.setTitle(localizedBack, for: .normal)
    navButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navButton)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

2. Click on the project, under navigation select project. Under localizations click +(plus) button and select the preferred language.
3. Create a "Localizable.strings" by right click on project folder, click new file, choose the template IOS, under resources select "String File" and give the name "Localizable".
4. In Localizable.strings file write this:

`"back" = "Back";` <- English file

`"back" = "Назад";` <- Russian file

Answer (score 1):

For Localization you can follow this link
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881)

```
 let strTitle = NSLocalizedString("Back", comment: "")
```

Default back button on navigation bar

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = strTitle
```

custom button on navigation bar

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    let  backBtn = UIButton()
    backBtn.backgroundColor = .red
    backBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40)
    backBtn.setTitle(strTitle, for: .normal)
    backBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backBtnAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let leftBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarBtn

   @objc func backBtnAction(sender:UIButton)
  {
    //back button action
  }
```

Comment: None of this is needed. But if you wanted to do this, why use a UIButton? Why not a normal UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated answer according default back button tile